# Netbeans 8 and Xdebug

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, ini

I just installed OSX Mavericks, and upgraded to Netbeans 8 PHP/HTML5.

In my previous install Netbeans 7.2 everything worked great and i had local debugging, through xdebug and MAMP.

After installing the new netbeans i no longer have access to xdebug. I try to debug the cli script it runs through...never connects to xdebug and i see the waiting bar.

The script will run all the way through and it will just continue with the (waiting-to-connect) until i manually end the xdebug session.

After ending it. I can no longer run The Run Project or Debug Project buttons. They just do nothing.

I am using MAMP and have edited all php.ini i can find with this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debu$
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

php --ini returns the .ini in /etc
php_ini_loaded_file() through netbeans returns false.

Anyone know what else i can do to track down which ini file is being loaded.
Or know the problem here.

Like i said everything was working until i upgraded to netbeans 8.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the new MAMP it renamed the php.ini to php.ini.default.
Netbeans could not find it. i renamed php.ini.default to php.ini and now everything works

Answer (score -2):

We were with this problem in a new DELL machine. McAfee was blocking. Uninstalled McAfee and functioned normally.

Comment: It is unclear whether McAfee is even installed here; also on a DELL you're probably using Windows or Linux while the question is about OS X (which can act quite differently).